# MongoDB command line to show if a user exists (for puppet 'unless' clause)

Tags: mongodb, puppet

We are using MongoDB user based authentication, and I want to quickly run a command to check whether a user has already been created in the database, in order that puppet won't repeatedly attempt to create the user.

Here is how we check if the replica set has initialised:

```
/usr/bin/mongo --host ${members[0]} --quiet --eval 'rs.status().ok' | grep -q 1
```

Is a similar trick possible with authentication? I've checked the documentation here http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/dbshell+%28mongo%29+Reference and I can't see a way of doing it?

Answer (score 20):

Yes, on a given DB, you can use `db.system.users.find({user:'login'}).count()` which will return 0 if the user does not exist.

Comment: Are you sure about having to use `db.system`? Shouldn't `db.users.find(...).count()` do the same?

Comment: `db.users.find(...).count()` will return the number of documents that are stored in the `users` collection. This collection is not special and is not related to the MongoDB Authentication process.

Comment: Ah, ok. I thought the OP was talking about a normal collection named users, not about the users of the database itself.

Answer (score 4):

It feels that this method has been deprecated, I needed the following command to work:

```
db.getUsers({filter: {'user': 'login'}})
```

Answer (score 2):

Today I just tried `-u` and `-p` options for `mongo` command and it worked for me:

```
mongo --port 27037 --quiet -u superuser -p pwd 
    --eval "db.system.users.find({user:'user3'}).count()" admin
```

Note the last "admin" arg - it is the name of database, to which you are authenticating.

Answer (score 0):

To check if a user `username` exists:

```
db.runCommand({ usersInfo: { user: "username", db: "admin" } }).users.length == 1
```

This will return `true` if the user exists, and `false` otherwise.  (If the user was created in another database, replace `admin` with the name of the database.)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `findOne`

`db.system.users.findOne({user:'login'})`

- it will `null` if no user
- it will return user if found